# Abort user request with Node.js/formidable

Tags: web-services, http, node.js, httprequest

I'm using formidable to receive a file upload with node.js. I send some fields together with a file in a multipart request.

As soon as certain fields arrived, I'm able to validate the authenticity of the request for instance, and I would like to abort the whole request if this is not correct to avoid waisting resources.

I have not found a right way to abort the incoming request. I tried to use `req.connection.destroy();` as follow:

```
form
.on('field', function(field, value) {
    fields[field] = value;
    if (!fields['token'] || !fields['id'] || !fields['timestamp']) {
        return;
    }
    if (!validateToken(fields['token'], fields['id'], fields['timestamp'])) {
        res.writeHead(401, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain' });
        res.end('Unauthorized');
        req.connection.destroy();
    }
})
```

However, this triggers the following error:

```
events.js:45
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: Cannot resume() closed Socket.
    at Socket.resume (net.js:764:11)
    at IncomingMessage.resume (http.js:254:15)
    at IncomingForm.resume (node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:52:11)
    at node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:181:12
    at node_modules/formidable/lib/file.js:51:5
    at fs.js:1048:7
    at wrapper (fs.js:295:17)
```

I also tried `req.connection.end()` but the file keeps uploading.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm also interested in this. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I was almost ready to write a duplicate question for this issue? Any ideas so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that formidable didn't understand that you want it to stop. Try this:

```
req.connection.destroy();
req.connection.resume = function(){};
```

Of course, this is a somewhat ugly workaround, I'd [open an issue on github](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/issues).